Set cookie on thank you page after form submission
I'm trying to establish a cookie upon form submission. How can I ensure the cookie is set on the thank you page when a user submits the form from a different page?
Form exists on http://www.example.com/
Cookie to be creatd on http://www.example.com/thank-you
Below is the code I am currently using
jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: actionURL,
        
         data: form.serialize(),
         dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
            window.location.href = "http://www.example.com/thank-you";
$.cookie("newcookie", "new", { path: "/thank-you", expires: 365 });
           
        }
    })


Can you please clarify what the issue is supposed to be? You are sending the user to the root path there in your AJAX success handler - so how do they actually get to the thank you page?

Why not put the cookie creation on the thank-you page?

you need to set cookie before redirection .and thankyou page you can get the cookie.
jQuery.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: actionURL,
         data: form.serialize(),
         dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
            $.cookie("newcookie", "new", { path: "/thank-you", expires: 365 });// set your cookie here before redirection.
 window.location.href = "http://www.example.com/thank-you";
           
        }
    })

